# How to check whether the program is being used?

Tags: c#, winforms, logging

I need to close the application (C#) when user doesn't use it - let's say that when there is no Click event on any form of the program (there are about 100 forms). Is there any way to do that without handling Click even on each form of the app. (I have the thread running each minute, where it could be checked)? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Lucas answer is good but this could also help: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0c6e496b-44d3-49ee-9ef0-282f079e363b/automatic-application-shutdown

Comment: what if a background process is running ??

Comment: @Eliasz go through [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30345/Application-Idle) and [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13756/Detecting-Application-Idleness)

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30345/Application-Idle

Answer (score 2):

You can hook into the application message loop using the [`Application.AddMessageFilter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.addmessagefilter.aspx) function. Write a message filter that inspects all mouse click messages and/or keyboard messages, or anything you're interested in.

For instance:

```
public class DetectActivityMessageFilter : IMessageFilter
{
    private const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201;

    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_LBUTTONDOWN)
        {
            // The left mouse button was pressed
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```